# Using Node to handle PushState redirects with nested backbone directories

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, backbone.js, express

I am a bit confused on how to deal with the Backbone hashes and pushState.

Basically I want

```
localhost:3004/#/explore
```

to be

```
localhost:3004/explore
```

and

```
localhost:3004/#/profile/123456
```

to be

```
localhost:3004/profile/123456
```

The first thing was specify all my static directories, which seems to work, since i could access all the files directly via the browser.

```
app.configure(function(){


    app.use("/js", express.static( path.join(__dirname, 'www/js')));
    app.use("/assets", express.static( path.join(__dirname, 'www/assets')));
    app.use("/style", express.static( path.join(__dirname, 'www/style')));
    app.use("/templates", express.static( path.join(__dirname, 'www/templates')));
    app.use("/config", express.static( path.join(__dirname, 'www/config')));

    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.session({
        secret: 'adasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd'
    }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(allowCrossDomain);
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(clientDir));

});
```

This seems to work since I could now navigate to any file from the location bar.

I'm also set up to use pushState

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
```

Where I am confused is in capturing the initial page call and making sure it hits index.html. However it also needs to pass in the directories so BackBones router knows where to go.

A couple unsuccessful attempts include:

```
app.get("*", function(req, res) {
    fs.createReadStream(path.join(clientDir, 'index.html')).pipe(res);
});
```

another

```
 app.get("*", function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('http://localhost:3004#/'+req.url);
});
```

another

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(path.join(clientDir, 'index.html'));
});
```

any ideas would be helpful.

I am open to other methods, such as htaccess, etc., although not sure how that would work with heroku deployments.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this works for me.

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res){
   res.sendfile(path.join(clientDir, 'index.html'));
});
```